# Wordpress header imgage won't display in IE

Tags: image, wordpress, internet-explorer, header

Image in header displays in Safari, FFX and Opera, but **not** in IE (on 9, btw).

Not sure if this matters, but when using IE's developer tools, it shows "Empty Text Node" all over the place.

I don't even know what other code to attach to this post...let me know.

site url: http://glassinfusion.accountsupport.com/

Header Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />

    <?php if (is_search()) { ?>
       <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" /> 
    <?php } ?>

    <title>
           <?php
              if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
                 single_tag_title("Tag Archive for &quot;"); echo '&quot; - '; }
              elseif (is_archive()) {
                 wp_title(''); echo ' Archive - '; }
              elseif (is_search()) {
                 echo 'Search for &quot;'.wp_specialchars($s).'&quot; - '; }
              elseif (!(is_404()) && (is_single()) || (is_page())) {
                 wp_title(''); echo ' - '; }
              elseif (is_404()) {
                 echo 'Not Found - '; }
              if (is_home()) {
                 bloginfo('name'); echo ' - '; bloginfo('description'); }
              else {
                  bloginfo('name'); }
              if ($paged>1) {
                 echo ' - page '. $paged; }
           ?>
    </title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

    <link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>



<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">

    <!-- start logo -->

 <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><span><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></span>
       <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo3.jpg" width="" height=""alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"/> 
        </a></h1> 

     <!-- End Logo -->


<?php
        /* A sidebar on top of the content? Yep. You can can customize
         * your top with three columns of widgets.
         */
        get_sidebar('navigation');
?>


</div><!--end header -->


<!-- start middle -->
<div id="middle">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with different format image like gif instead of jpg in the case of those images which are not displaying.

Comment: Close...it needed to be .png! .gif didn't work. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: Please select this answer and vote to approve the answer- thanks